# Properly process multiple pasted lines into Java command line

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

How can I paste multiple lines into a Java 8 console application?
Simple thing but I don't manage to catch the last line using Scanner.
Found various topics but none for String lines (they all waited for integer etc.).

I'd like to past in the following scheme (e.g. from editor):

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

The lines have "\n" endings but Java omits the last line (because it doesn't end with "\n" I assume).

It doesn't matter for me if pushing ENTER is necessary in the end or the paste ending will be detected automatic.
Only thing I achieve though is that line 0 to 3 are printed immediately and line 4 only after ENTER was has been (which enforces a new line).
This results in an unpleasant mix:

```
line0
line1
line2
line3 (I have to press ENTER now)

line4
```

Each line will passed into another function, for better understanding I use "println".

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter lines: \r\n");

        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
        sc.close();
```

Also tried with various "useDelimiter" combinations and "do...while" instead of "while" but without success.

The same thing with ArrayList didn't lead to an end at all (neither after pressing ENTER nor after adding 'if line != null' statement):

```
    public static ArrayList<String> inputLines = new ArrayList<String>();

       while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            inputLines.add(sc.next());
        }
        sc.close();

        inputLines.forEach((inputLine) -> System.out.println(inputLine));
```

TIA ... I despair ...

Comment: but this is a *restriction* of the operating system, or more precisely, of the shell - it only sends a line after the linefeed (ENTER) is pressed/given (maybe the user wants to delete/edit something before sending the input)

Comment: *How can I post multiple lines into a Java 8 console application?* I'm not sure what you mean by "post" but if you want lines as input, why not read a file?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Meant "paste".
Alright but weird thing is that the IntelliJ terminal directly starts to interpret the lines as soon as it detects the linefeed. Maybe it's more effective to use a control sign?

Comment: Yes, that's a kind of fake terminal so its behaviour is sort of arbitrary. In any case, apps are for users, not devs, and users don't use IDEs.